# logrotate even empty files

Tags: cron, logrotate

I have a problem running `logrotate` in a cron job: files that are too small in size don't get rotated.

I want all files, even those with size equal to 0 to be rotated.
Here is my config

```bash
/logs/server-*.log {
    rotate 1
    missingok
    compress
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
    dateext
    dateformat %Y-%m-%d-%s
    lastaction
    # scripts to move *.gz files here
    endscript
}
```

Please advise.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 server

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you ask is now the default Logrotate behaviour. However, you can explicitly add the `ifempty` configuration:

```bash
/logs/server-*.log {

    # Rotate the log file even if it is empty, 
    # overriding the notifempty option (ifempty is the default).
    ifempty

    rotate 1
    missingok
    compress
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
    dateext
    dateformat %Y-%m-%d-%s
    lastaction
    # scripts to move *.gz files here
    endscript
}
```